# Can you please tell me the role of "bit of pork" here

Tags: meaning

"Without any real warning, **he would offer you outside over who ate the last bit of pork** we'd all had a whip for, or if he thought you were laughing at him not with him, the fallout out could be downright dangerous"

Colin Swan "True story of the Exits"

I don't understand the bolded part. Why does it talk about the last bit of pork? Does it mean the man wanted to go outside (he was in a pub) to fight because he did not have the last bit of pork.

The author gives this example to show that he was really dangerous and that he fought for less than nothing . A bit of pork for the author is not a reason to start a fight

Comment: It means pretty much what you suggest it does. What you seem to be querying is the motivations of the author, and I don't think we can answer that here. But if the book is written in the first person then it isn't the author who asks to fight over things - it is whoever 'he' is.

Comment: "offer you outside" is quite odd. There is something wrong. bit of pork is just piece of  pork.

Comment: _We'd all had a whip_ presumably refers to what is normally called a _whip-round_ - when a group of people contribute money, usually to buy someone a present, but maybe here they had bought a joint of pork to share?

Comment: I can't find the title "Tue story of the exits" by Colin Swan. I can only find "The Exits", which appears to be a band connected to Colin Swan.

Comment: I can only guess that maybe "He'd offer you outside" means, "He'd invite you to go outside (with him and fight)". Either way, it's certainly not idiomatic or natural, and not a sentence worth learning English from.

Comment: yes Colin Swan is or was a musician . His first band was called the Exits, they only   made a single in 1978. At last their lp is out (it has been for a few days )  . Colin wrote a little text for the inner sleeve and this sentence comes from the text

Comment: @gotube I can't argue it's not a sentence worth learning English from, but as for 'it's certainly not idiomatic or natural', you should have finished that sentence with 'in Ontario'. It's slangy, but that's all

Comment: It's a peculiar style. Feasibly authentic dialect, but I kinda doubt it. Looks more like "literary artistic license" with some of the vocabulary / phrasing here. Not a good text for the average learner to learn from.

Comment: @Au101 Where or during what era do you think that is/was natural speech, even natural slangy speech?

Comment: @gotube Try typing "offered me outside" (in quotes) into Google and see what you get. Trying this in Britain I get a few examples. From Facebook "That egg is so hard it's offered me outside!!" From Trustpilot "When questioned the guy said I didn't know what I was talking about, when I disagreed he offered me outside and became vile." From Pubs Galore "As I was finishing up some drunk Irishman sat down next to me, growled "black and tan c**t", spat on the table and then offered me outside."

Comment: @gotube "Offer out" is common enough for a newspaper headline https://www.loughboroughecho.net/news/local-news/called-townie-offered-out-5812223 and a slang dictionary http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/english-slang/o.htm and the more explicit "offer out for a fight" is so common and transparent it hardly seems worth quoting Sean Lock https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWuiXF_6vR4&t=15s

Comment: @Au101 Thanks! Learn something every day

Comment: @gotube Aww pleasure, sorry for the earlier snarkiness, must have left my politeness on the bus!

Comment: @Au101 All good! You've earned yourself a mention in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "offer someone outside" means to [challenge someone to a fight](http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/english-slang/o.htm). This is British slang that sheltered Ontarians like myself have never heard.

"Over" is a preposition commonly used to indicate the issue that caused people to want to fight.

"to have a whip(-round) for something" means to get everyone in a group to [chip some money in to buy something collectively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whip-round). This is also British slang that ign'ant Ontarians like myself have never heard.

And "a bit of pork" is "some pork".

So the overall gist of this sentence is that this guy would pick fights with someone for finishing off some meat they'd all purchased together.

---

I pulled this answer together from the comments, so credit to Au101 and Kate Bunting.